# how to create Browse button in salesforce using visualforce coding

Tags: salesforce

click on Browse button  searching for file i want like that .kindly let me know

Comment: file from where, salesforce, your local machine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple html code for generating file browse button in visual force.

Comment: ok i created browse button.but click on browse button choose some file and stored i want like this.please tell me.

Comment: Please mention your hole problem then i hope i will give your andwar